# Onepage Layout in Typo3

Tags: templates, typo3, typoscript

i already have a Onepage HTML template and now I want to show the content from Typo3 inside it. 
How is it possible to show content of different subpages at only one page?

Are there any examples?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like Typoscript you can easily create a onepager with viewhelpers of the VHS Extension.

The only thing I did with Typoscript is adding Layouts to `pages`.

```
TCEFORM.pages.layout {
    removeItems = 1,2,3
    altLabels.0 = None
    addItems {
        10 = Class 1
        20 = Class 2
        30 = Class 3
        40 = Class 4
    }
}
```

This Layouts you can use to create different styles inside the onepager.

I use something like this in my page-template:

```
<main>
    <v:page.menu pageUid="1" as="page">
        <f:for each="{page}" as="pageObject">
            <f:render partial="OnepagerContainer" section="Main" arguments="{pageObject:pageObject}"/>
        </f:for>
    </v:page.menu>
</main>
```

`pageUid="1"` is the top page in your pagetree, wich subpages should be rendered in the onepager.

And the Partial thats rendered there looks like:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"
      xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
      xmlns:v="http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Vhs/ViewHelpers"
      data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">

<f:section name="Main">

    <f:switch expression="{pageObject.layout}">
        <f:case value="10">
            <v:variable.set name="containerClass" value="container-class1"/>
        </f:case>
        <f:case value="20">
            <v:variable.set name="containerClass" value="container-class2"/>
        </f:case>
        .
        .
        .
    </f:switch>

    <div id="anchor-{pageObject.uid}" class="container{f:if(condition: containerClass, then:' {containerClass}')}">
        <div class="col-12">
            <v:content.render pageUid="{pageObject.uid}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</f:section>

</html>
```

After rendering, this looks like:

```
<main>
    <div id="anchor-2" class="container container-tiles">
        <div class="col-12"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam</p></div>
    </div>
    <div id="anchor-3" class="container">
        <div class="col-12"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum</p></div>
    </div>
    <div id="anchor-4" class="container">
        <div class="col-12"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum</p></div>
    </div>
    <div id="anchor-5" class="container">
        <div class="col-12"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="anchor-6" class="container">
        <div class="col-12"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="anchor-7" class="container">
        <div class="col-12"></div>
    </div>
</main>
```

The ID in `<div id="anchor-4" class="container"></div>` is created with the PID (anchor-[pid]).
Now you can create a navigation which uses this anchor-IDs to scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

The most difficult aspect might be that the setup for a `onepager` is just not typical in TYPO3. Nevertheless TYPO3 is probably one of the best systems to realize your request as it's very easy to crawl and sort content from several pages.

Assume a setup like this:

```
page = PAGE
page {
    10 = CONTENT
    10 {
        table = tt_content
        select {
            where = colPos = 0
            pidInList = 10,11,12,13,14,15
            orderBy = crdate
        }
    }
}
```

Like this you get all content-elements from the pages where the uid is in a range from 10-15. Sorting is done with the command `orderBy` and the field `cr_date` as value.

I must admit, sorting here might not be what you need and the required sorting is different than you can achieve by adding a single sorting-field for all pages.
No reason to get distressed, just collect the data step by step:

```
page = PAGE
page {
    10 = CONTENT
    10 {
        table = tt_content
        select {
            where = colPos = 0
            pidInList = 10
            orderBy = crdate
        }
    }

    20 = CONTENT
    20 {
        table = tt_content
        select {
            where = colPos = 0
            pidInList = 11
            orderBy = subheader
        }
    }

    30 = CONTENT
    30 {
        table = tt_content
        select {
            where = colPos = 0
            pidInList = 12
            orderBy = header
        }
    }
}
```

Above the records for each page are sorted by a different field, so you see there is some more variation possible.
If that's not enough as sorting-option it's still possible to retrieve a list of single records from the database. I'm not 100% sure at the moment but I suppose the sorting of the content-uids determines the sorting of the data you get:

```
page = PAGE
page {
    10 = CONTENT
    10 {
        table = tt_content
        select {
            where = colPos = 0
            uidInList = 33,34,355,556,789
        }
    }
}
```

All the requirements can be solved by TypoScript and it's possible still to include much more difficult scenarios.
[Here you find the reference for TypoScript.](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/)

After getting the data the content is usually rendered always with the same setup.
But it would be possible to render it with different functions and using different content-templates. 
Some very rudimentary options to render are shown on [this page](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html) but if you dig a bit deeper in TYPO3 you can render each data-set individually.
Be advised that rendering might not be so important anymore if you work with fluid-templates as many things can be done in the templates.

Answer (score -1):

```
temp.content = COA
temp.content {
    10 = CONTENT
    10 {
        table = pages
        select {
            pidInList.field = uid
            orderBy = sorting ASC
        }
        renderObj = COA
        renderObj {
            10 = CONTENT
            10 {
                table = tt_content
                select {
                    languageField = sys_language_uid
                    pidInList.field = uid
                    orderBy = sorting
                }
                stdWrap.wrap = |
            }
        }
    }
}
```

... but from your question I'd say you are beginning to use TYPO3 ...

In that case I suggest you use the following extension : [EXT:t3sbootstrap](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/t3sbootstrap/) from the repository ... (this is only your first hang-up)

Out of the box it does allow your request, and you can slowly figure out how its done by dissecting the extension !!

big advantages:

1. you have your site up and running in no time.
2. great documentation (if you speak german ...) [Website](https://www.t3sbootstrap.de/demo/onepagelayout/)
3. its the right recommended way to code with extbase

I know it seems opinionated, but its really the best suggestion I can give you ... (if your template is bootstrap v3 just go for older versions, like 3.2.43 (which I prefer anyway))

if this does not suit you, you'll have to build a custom distribution which is well documented in the [TYPO3 docs](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ExtensionArchitecture/CreateNewDistribution/Index.html)

old but always good: [PanadeEdu on Yoututbe](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCW9tyEGR2EJ1vKSbWIVjCuQ) (always in german) with a specific film on [the template](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rclwzW4gx1c)

and another very complete serie: [Wolfgang wagner on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kR_Ihpae7gs&list=PLC0B9C876DA340605), just have your pick of the subject (he has a video-course for sale too)

it is said that TYPO3 is fun, its kind of a headache in the beginning but what you learn using it will get you in the upper 10% of programming !!!